# How do PHP libraries that interface PHP with database systems actually call the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, system-calls

I've been looking through the Predis code on GitHub and it's massive so it's a bit difficult for me figure this out from just looking at the code because I don't understand what each folder/file is for

What I'd like to know is, how does PHP actually contact the database when using MySQL or Redis or any other database system? Does it make system calls similar to how you can do in C with `system("some command here");` or does the developer have to actually extend the compiler for the PHP language to do this?

Comment: MySQL has an API available in many languages, including C, which is the underlying language in which PHP is generally developed. The `mysql_*()` functions in PHP are basically a direct 1:1 mapping between PHP and the underlying C API functions. Other MySQL libraries will ALSO use the same C api. They do **NOT** use `exec()` or whatever to invoke mysql from a command line. That'd be HIDEOUSLY inefficient and utterly break the necessicty of keeping a connection alive for things like transactions.

Comment: PHP includes a number of database extensions that provide the interface. See the [reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php)

Comment: Most interface wrappers use an existing PHP extension written in C. Most [SQL databases are covered](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php) by PHP already. The Predis wrapper [says on its github page](https://github.com/nrk/predis) it's using [libredis](http://redis.io/) which a [PECL extension exists for](http://pecl.php.net/package/redis). More uncommon, but quite feasible are also userland interfaces using [socket communication](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) to whatever database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to "extend the compiler", but you have to do what you probably meant by this: write a PHP module/extension *in C* that talks to the database's (typically) C library API. What does that mean? A database typically comes with connector libraries that are often written in low level C and thereby offer a C based API. That more or less works like an `include 'api.php'` which then allows you to call functions of whatever you just included, but it's specific to C. PHP code cannot talk to C code directly, but a PHP extension written in C can act as a "bridge" between PHP code and the C API.

That C library then has many options how it may talk to the actual database. It may talk directly to another C API of the database, though that's not necessarily typical. Often a UNIX socket or TCP socket is used, sometimes across the network if the database is on a different machine. You *could* be talking directly to that UNIX/TCP socket from your PHP code if you wanted to, but that means you'd have to reimplement the entire protocol to talk to the database in PHP code. That's typically inefficient, since PHP is a rather high level language and doesn't offer any direct access to raw computer resources like memory, which makes this implementation rather inefficient.

So, the way it typically goes is:

- the database offers a protocol to talk to it over a socket of some kind
- an official protocol client is implemented in a C library, because it's efficient and portable
- someone writes a PHP extension to bridge that C library API into PHP userland code

There's nothing stopping you from implementing that protocol in other languages in alternative clients, but since this is often a tedious process and C is a widely used system, people typically end up writing wrappers around the existing official C library.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant - Writing an extension.

Answer (score 1):

The functions/classes for interacting with the various databases are provided (like pretty much everything in PHP) by PHP extensions, e.g. the mysqli extension.  They are .so files on Linux or .dlls on Windows.  Or they can be compiled into PHP when it's built.  Either way, they call functions in the Zend code to register the functions/classes that will be called in PHP (e.g. mysqli_connect) and hook them up to code that knows how to interact with the database.  PHP and the extensions are written in C.  If you look at examples of how to write C code that connects to MySQL, that's probably what the mysqli/mysql extensions in PHP use.